# Migrate Java EAR project from Maven to Bazel?

Tags: java, maven, bazel

I have a Java Enterprise application consisting of multiple modules (several WARs and JARs and 1 Angular5 module) built and packaged into 1 thin **EAR**.

From a functional perspective the **Maven** projectstructure works fine, everything is modularized, with unittests, integration tests etc working fine.

However, due to buildspeed reasons I am looking into alternatives for Maven and **Bazel** keeps popping up more and more.

I have Bazel installed and have followed the simple example JAR tutorial, which works fine. I have some questions before even attempting to spec and migrate to Bazel as a POC:

1. Am I correct in my assumption that I can gain a significant build speed improvement with Bazel over Maven for this kind of project?
2. Are there examples to build a WAR module or EAR module with Bazel?
3. My plan is to add the BUILD files next to the POMs as long as I am experimenting. Any downsides to that?
4. Bazel seems very powerful since it lets me script about anything. This may also be a downside, since in Maven there are so many plugins for about anything. Any thoughts on the maintainability of the scripts or Bazel structure?
5. I am running on Windows instead of Linux (yes.. I know). Any downsides to that in relation to Bazel? Everything seems to work fine and fast with MSYS2.

Thanks!
I'd love to hear about success stories with implementing Bazel for a Java Enterprise app..

Comment: Actually I would think twice before I'll change from the major player of Java build (Maven) to a niche tool. If you run into problems with Maven, SO is here to help, but with Bazel, the situation will be much worse.

Comment: First if you are talking about build speed. How many modules do you have ? Which Maven version do you use? How long takes a build? Are you using parallel builds (-T)? Are we talking about a build speed on the CI solution like Jenkins? How long do your tests take of the build time? etc. ? Furthermore based on the docs of Bazel you need to have Python ? Why for a Java build ?

Comment: My modules:

 - 4 JAR modules
 - 2 WAR modules
 - 1 Angular5 module
 - 1 EAR module bundling it all

In total my current build takes 15 minutes excluding unittests, with -T 4 for parallization.

That is on Jenkins, in dev laptops it&#39;s about 10 minutes for a full build.

If Python is required then so be it.

I am just interested in speeding up the complete build process and rebuild process.

Comment: First what kind of machine do you use? It sounds you are using the oldest machines you could ever get..I've worked on a project with 800+ modules running without `-T` 20 Minutes and with `-T` it drills down to 6 minutes including 5500+ unit tests. But we used SSD based machines and to be honest this size of project I build on my laptop in less than a minute...(I Tested one with 24 modules 1 minute)..So to me that sounds you should invest in more up-to-date hardware which is less effort than changing the whole build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm an engineer on the Bazel team.

> Am I correct in my assumption that I can gain a significant build
>   speed improvement with Bazel over Maven for this kind of project?

This will depend on how fast your current builds with Maven are, as well as the characteristics of your build graph.

The company Redfin migrated from Maven to Bazel last year and experienced a 10x speedup in their CI builds (40-90 mins to 5-6 mins). [They have documented this migration experience on their blog](https://redfin.engineering/we-switched-from-maven-to-bazel-and-builds-got-10x-faster-b265a7845854). Earlier this year, Bazel added support for [remote caching](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/remote-caching.html), which users have reported to speed their builds up further.

> Are there examples to build a WAR module or EAR module with Bazel?

There is the [`java_war` packaging rule in `rules_appengine`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_appengine#java_war). Bazel is extensible, so if the rules for a particular build step doesn't exist, it can be written as a [rule extension](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html) (e.g. [this list of community rules](https://github.com/jin/awesome-bazel#rules))

> My plan is to add the BUILD files next to the POMs as long as I am
>   experimenting. Any downsides to that?

`BUILD`/`BUILD.bazel` files are not intrusive to your project and should not affect your existing Maven builds.

> Bazel seems ver powerful since it lets me script about anything. This
>   may also be a downside, since in Maven there are so many plugins for
>   about anything. Any thoughts on the maintainability of the scripts or
>   Bazel structure?

This is a pretty subjective question, and it depends on what plugins you're dependent on.

One migration step you might run into is the management of transitive external dependencies. There's an excellent tool called [`bazel-deps`](https://github.com/johnynek/bazel-deps) that helps you manage them and generates the BUILD files automatically.

[`Jadep` is another tool](https://github.com/bazelbuild/tools_jvm_autodeps/) that parses your Java project and generates `BUILD` files for them. Check out [this guide](https://github.com/cgrushko/text/blob/master/migrating-gjf-to-bazel.md) for more on Jadep.

> I am running on Windows instead of Linux (yes.. I know). Any downsides
>   to that in relation to Bazel? Everything seems to work fine and fast
>   with MSYS2.

Bazel is a Windows-native binary and does not depend on the MSYS2 runtime, unless you use rules that depend on `bash`, like `sh_library`. Check out this blogpost for more: https://blog.bazel.build/2017/10/16/windows-retrospect.html